# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: composite key in query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to fetch the list of records from a view which has a composite primary key with three columns.

I tried to embed the `composite key` in the `entity class`. But I am getting the below mentioned errors. The columns of the views (VW_ALERTS) are `C_ID`, `MAT_ID`, `P_MONTH`, `CO_TYPE`, `CO_SUBTYPE`.

Here the composite keys are `C_ID, MAT_ID, P_MONTH`. I am making the property of them in the embeddable class.

Please help to resolve the issue

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: coreId of: com.sp.cpem.dto.VwAlerts [FROM com.ct.cpem.dto.VwAlerts d ORDER BY d.cId ASC]
```

This following code is used to execute the hql.

```
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            String hql = "FROM VwAlerts d ORDER BY d.coId ASC";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            return query.list();
```

The entity class :

```
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Entity
            @Table(schema = "TIGER", name = "VW_ALERTS")
            public class VwAlerts {

                @Embedded
                private VwAlertsPK vwAlertsPK;

                @Basic
                @Column(name = "CO_TYPE", nullable = true)
                private String coType;

                @Basic
                @Column(name = "CO_SUBTYPE", nullable = true)
                private String coSubType;
```

Class used to get the composite key

```
 @Embeddable
            public class VwAlertsPK  implements Serializable {
                @Basic
                @Column(name = "C_ID", nullable = false)
                private BigDecimal cId;

                @Basic
                @Column(name = "MAT_ID", nullable = true)
                private BigDecimal matId;

                @Basic
                @Column(name = "P_MONTH", nullable = true)
                private BigDecimal pMonth;
```

I am expecting to get all the records from the view. 
I tried with the `@Id` column in the entity class, it failed by returning only the duplicate records of the first row from the view.

Comment: Are there any missing fields that you maybe skipped in class `VwAlerts` and `VwAlertsPK` while posting?

Answer (score 0):

Your entity `VwAlerts` has only 3 properties --> `vwAlertsPK, coType, coSubType`

but in your HQL you are trying to access a property `coreId` which does not exist in your entity.

```
FROM com.ct.cpem.dto.VwAlerts d ORDER BY d.coreId ASC
```

So add the property `coreId` to your entity or else just update the `ORDER BY` clause so you are pointing to correct properties of your entity.

Comment: Please read my answer properly, you don't have that property in your Java class (means your entity) so why you are trying to use that in HQL

Comment: I changed to "FROM com.ct.cpem.dto.VwAlerts d ORDER BY d.VwAlertsPK.cId ASC". But now I get the lists required count. When I iterate the list, it provides me the null objects.

Comment: @Renga, I am not able to understand what error you are getting now, please update your question and provide details on what you have tried and what exception you are getting with complete stacktrace of the error. Also give complete information about your entities, it is not easy for anyone to guess what properties you have in your entities.

Comment: Renga, I have a hunch your problem now is that you're referencing "VwAlertsPK" when the field entry has a lowercase v at the beginning.